# How do I turn a PHP variable string to output HTML?

Tags: php, string, email, variables, output

I am trying to create an autoresponder email and the content is a PHP variable. I want it to output HTML code and right now it's not.

```
//Example:
$respondmessage = " Hello $fullname,
 We are confirming your Appointment today!
Please <a href="http://yourlink.com/">click here to confirm</a>!
";
```

This outputs:

```
Hello Your Name,
 We are confirming your Appointment today!
Please <a href="http://yourlink.com/">click here to confirm</a>!
```

In the email. Is there a way to make the email accept HTML code?

Comment: How are you sending the email? You can send emails in HTML format, but by default they'll be plain text.

Comment: Show the entire relevant PHP code. BTW you forgot to put backslash before the double-quotes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the built in `mail` function in PHP:

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

This example is from: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

The important part is the `$headers` variable.

By the way, as andrewsi mentioned - you need to escape your quotes:

```
$respondmessage = "Hello $fullname,
    We are confirming your Appointment today!
    Please <a href=\"http://yourlink.com/\">click here to confirm</a>!";
```

Comment: This looks like what I need! Thank you! I will test this out in an hour or so and let you know how it works for me! I looked up something earlier and it said something about the charset but couldn't find a definite answer. Thanks again! Will let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You can following line as an header in your code :

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

This will help you to create email into HTML

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this header to  your email script

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php example# 4

```
<?php

// multiple recipients
$to = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Birthday Reminders for August';

// message
$message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```